# migrate cocoa touch project to cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I used the codes below to access the variable in the project

```
appDelegate =(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIApplication *app=[UIApplication sharedApplication];
appDelegate.myInt=1;
```

It works.

But when I try to migrate the project to Cocoa, I found there is no way to do the same functions as above.
How can I use delegate concept to access the global variables (not use 'extern NSInteger myInt')

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [NSApplication](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class documentation